# Bottom of button disappears on different computers with same environment

Tags: java, swing, layout, jbutton

I'm facing issue with Java Swing. On one computer button looks [one way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHGLw.png), but on other computers it's [different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7glJv.png). Any idea why?

[image] 
[image]

Environment description (every computer):

- Java 1.8.0_171
- Windows 10

Comment: Could it be a screen resolution or font availability issue?

Comment: Probably a bug of your layout. This could be when you use null-layout, espacially when user increas DPI to 125 or 150%

Comment: To help with the problem isolation, please consider posting a [MCVE]. Without any access to your code it's hard to tell what could have caused this.